# Write negative float values in XML file to a binary file with some sanity checks

Tags: python, xml, binary

I have an xml file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Title Report Weblink>
<Header>
<More titles>
<a>-1.3e-2</a>
<b>-0.1e-1</b>
```

and I have a total of about 200,000 of these a's and b's. I would like to fetch these a's and b's and store it into a binary. I need to use this further in my algorithm and access each of these a's and b's. Each a has be mapped to its b, of course.

The main purpose of this conversion is to compress the data and store the values (a's and b's) in a binary file.

So far I tried this importing struct and array in Python but couldn't do it successfully.  The problem is it stores the values but I cannot access each of these a's and b's.

I also have to do a sanity check later to see if the headline of the binary file and the xml file are the same. If not, I should generate the latest binary file.

Comment: 1) can you add an example of what you already tried? 

2) did you consider the dictionary structure? This could be a solution if the a-value (or b-value) is the key to the other value. It can only be used if a or b values are unique. otherwise you could use a list of tuples?

Comment: What _precisely_ do you mean by "binary file"? Do you want to convert the a and b strings to floats and store the binary representation of those floats in a file?

Comment: I need to create a binary file to store the values of a and b. a and b are already negative float values in the xml file.

Comment: Well, I don't have anything concrete. I can convert only single float values into binary. The problem is, I need to store these values into tuples or lists or (preferably) arrays.